# SQLite: .db file extension to .sqlite file extension

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a .db file which came from a software application. I am trying to open it and use it in an android application. However, when I attempt to open it in SQLite Database Browser a warning appears and says that the file is not an SQLite 3 Database. I am able to open the file in Hex Editor and can see data mixed with a bunch of other text that I don't know what it means. How can I get a .db file openned in an android application if it is not an sqlite 3 database? Thanks.

Comment: Try to open it in the desktop version of some SQLite DBMS on your development machine (Windows, Mac, etc.). Just to verify that DB is not corrupt.

Comment: Just because a file has a .db extension does not mean it can be opened by SQLite.  You need to know what kind of DB it is then include the appropriate libs to work with that type of database.  There are many types of DB and they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQLite file is correct for the android database then just change the extension of your file and it will able to use it in to Android.

If it not solve your problem then use SQLite Database Manager. I am using SQLite Database Manager to create database and even also to change any values of the database. So, Use SQLiteDatabaseManager to make and change the database.

And yes, be sure that you have default android_metadata table in the database. For more information regarding the metadata see [this link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains a SQLite database your dump should start with something like this:

```
0000000: 5351 4c69 7465 2066 6f72 6d61 7420 3300  SQLite format 3.
0000010: 1000 0101 0040 2020 0000 0003 0000 0002  .....@  ........
```